# Can we access spring bean in Karate feature?

Tags: karate

I have a class like below, can I access the myServer object or call handleOperation() method (which can use the injected bean)  in Karate Feature file? If yes then may I know how?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApiApp.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AcceptanceTestConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:acceptanceTest/api/myapi.feature", tags = "@myapi")
public class MyAtddTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyServer myServer;

    public void handleOperation() throws Exception {
      myServer.handle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support for spring or the annotations. And not sure if you can mix the test annotations.

But take a look at the Spring MVC Dispatcher example here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-mock-servlet#mocking-your-servlet

Specifically how using Java interop you can do anything you want. I recommend getting the spring context using first-principles. For e.g:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AcceptanceTestConfiguration.class);
```

And then getting beans out of it. Setting a test profile via `System.setProperty()` should be simple, search for it. You can do all this in even the `karate-config.js` and then it should be easy to use from all `Scenario`-s.

EDIT - also refer: https://github.com/Sdaas/hello-karate

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I am using it by copying the bean in a static variable. It worked however somehow feeling that it's not the clean way.

Comment: @ernitingoel heh :) open to ideas. I can confirm we don't intend to add spring dependencies to karate core. maybe you can create a open source adapter that works with karate. my advice is this - these are just tests, just get the work done :P

Comment: Agreed, I know I was asking little more based on my use-case :)

Comment: @ernitingoel Did you implement it? I am looking for a similar situation. In my case, I want to mock some beans of spring class while testing using Karate.

Comment: @AnchikaAgarwal you won't get a "ready made" solution. read the link in the answer, and the code that is linked from there. all the info you need is there

Comment: @PeterThomas your link about karate-mock-servlet doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @jmizv see if this helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/v1.0.0/karate-mock-servlet#mocking-your-servlet

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution that doesn't re-create the context:

```java
package your.packageName;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class KarateUtil {
  private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    KarateUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  /**
   * This is used by our Karate to get spring beans.
   *
   * @throws org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException if the bean name isn't
   *     found
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static Object getSpringBean(String beanName) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
  }
}
```

because karate is able to call java static methods:

```
* def myBean = your.packageName.KarateUtil.getSpringBean('exactBeanName')
* eval myBean.anyMethod()
```

You can get all bean names with `applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()` or just assign a specific name to the bean.